# How to test if AWS SNS has delivered SMS successfully

Tags: manual-testing, aws

If there a mechanism I can validate if my SNS service has successfully pushed SMS on to customers phone  through logs or delivery status. And incase of failure an alert can be generated.

Does AWS provides any alert mechanism which we can capture during our testing for SNS.

Answer (score 3):

To track the delivery status of text messages sent via AWS SNS, you can use **Delivery status logging** feature which will log delivery status as success/failure. You can view logs in **CloudWatch**.

For detailed steps on how to configure, refer to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/

Comment: I assume then we can check logs for our testing. Do you any tool available in market which can test on devices as well ?Like buying virtual numbers

Comment: @SaurabhKumar There are many offering virtual numbers. For which country are you looking for?

Comment: I have list of 100 + countries. For example - Albania, Bahrain , Bahamas ,Cambodia , Georgia , Estonia, Jamaica , Kenya, Malta, Sri Lanka , Uzbekistan, Ukraine, Jordan and etc. I have checked Twilio they have Regulatory restrictions for buying virtual numbers where we have to upload the local address proof or local identity proof which my company won't be able to gather. So looking for a solution where we can check the SMS being delivered easily without giving some docs.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Not sure for all the countries. But check out these if it helps: https://www.avoxi.com/virtual-phone-numbers/ , https://www.textnow.com/

Comment: Thanks I will check .

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Welcome!! Do accept the answer if that has answered your question.